# How to add an UploadedFile to $request->files manually

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to upload a file which is already there in storage directory using code I want to merge that with my request.

How can I upload a file by code by passing `$request->file` manually to request?

Below code I am using to pass file manually but in controller I am not able to receive that file using `$request->file('image')`.

```
$data=[
'image'         => new \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile(storage_path('listing-demo/1.jpeg'),'1.jpeg'),
'input1' =>'output1',
'dummy2' =>'output2',
]

$request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
$request->replace($data);

app(MyRepo::class)->insert($request);
```

In My repository file I am not able to access file using $request->file('image').

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out a situation where it makes senso to create an UploadedFile from the internal storage, I'm really curious about your use case

Comment: what kind of file do you want to merge?

Comment: okay so whenever any user-created in our system I want to manually post 3 blogs for each user. and I am reusing blog post code where I am accessing image using $request->file  and I want to use same code to post blog manually by code @gbalduzzi

Comment: @OMiShah file can be jpeg , png

Comment: Then a better approach would be to create a separate class/function that accepts a list of files as argument, and call that from the controllers you need

Comment: perahps you may want to abstract that code so it only takes the data and creates the records, then you can reuse that code in both places ... in one you will be handling the uploaded file (moving it to get the new path) and the other just passing in the path ... either way by the time you call this code you only have to pass a file path and not deal with the UploadedFile

Comment: @gbalduzzi any how i need to pass that images as UploadedFile object is there any way I can ?

Comment: You could not access that file because you were not setting file data to the request object but your are setting input values. So you can access input values for example, `$request->input('image');`. But that's not the way you should do that. So please have a look at the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::class`'s constructor function to know how you can pass in file data in `Illuminate\Http\Request::class`.

Comment: i would rather see you refactor the functionality you need and use it in both places instead of calling another controller directly ... often a code smell

Comment: @joy you should do what lagbox suggests. That would be the way you should do otherwise your code would be tightly coupled.

Comment: @lagbox i am using my repository to store directly in db... sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: @unclexo i am using the repository pattern  from controller and from jobs I am calling directly to store data

Comment: then use your repository in both places ... the only difference would be that one method would be dealing with moving the uploaded file and the other would already have a path to a local file ... either way you are only saving the path to the file in the database

Comment: @lagbox i am uploading those image in s3

Answer (score 0):

Technically it should be possible, but practically not.

An uploaded file has many special attributes, one of them is to be a temporary file that gets deleted once done with the request or moved away.

What you should do is have a function (in a repository ?) that accept all variables needed to create the post, one of them is a file( or better, a file local link) to create a blog post. You can even make the user as an argument too.

This way you wont have to mok a request and call manually onto a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after so much debugging, I come to know that this is the way we can create a duplicate request with uploaded file object.

```
<?php


use App\Http\Helpers\ListingHelper;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

class SampleBlogCreator
{

    public function doCreate(User $user)
    {

        $helper = new ListingHelper($user->Store);
        foreach ($this->getData() as $data) {
            $request = (new Request())->duplicate($data['data'], [], [], [], $data['image']);
            $helper->insert($request);
        }
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return [
            [
                'image' => ['image' => new UploadedFile(base_path('public/imges/listing/5.jpg'), '1.jpeg', 'image/jpg', null, true)],
                'data'  => ["title"   => "What is Lorem Ipsum?",
                            "date"    => now()->toDateString(),
                            "content" => " Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    <br>
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of \"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, \"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..\", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
.",],

            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

If you want to know duplicate method parameter than go to this file **vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php**

Answer (score -4):

```
//write in the view blade
<input type="file" class="uploads form-control" name="cover">
//

// write it in your controller
if($request->file('cover')) {
        $file = $request->file('cover');
        $dt = Carbon::now();
        $acak  = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'-'.$dt->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s').'.'.$acak;
        $request->file('cover')->move("public/images", $fileName); 
        $cover = $fileName;
    }else {
        $cover = NULL;
    }

   $data = new Image();  //model your databse
   $data->image   = $cover;
   $data->save();
   }
```